# Is there a way to pull user's name using Google People API into a Google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-forms, google-people-api

I am trying to programatically create a Google form that will pull the students name in automatically.

I've looked at the Google People API documentation here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people and tried to add the example code they have and push the result as a response to a text question. I have the API enabled and I added the scope to the json file as instructed but nothing gets populated.

I know there is a checkbox to automatically grab their email address, but for reasons instead of using the students names for their email address we use their student ID numbers for their email address, so the data isn't very useful for our purposes here.

Here is my code with some information redacted.

```
function myFunction() {
var form = FormApp.create('NHS Student Information Survey');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();
var listofteachernames = [];

var people = People.People.getBatchGet({
    resourceNames: ['people/me'],
    personFields: 'names'
  });


form.setDescription(
"High School \n"+
"Address \n"+
"Mr. teacher, NHS Advisor \n"+
" \n"+
"Submissions are due before date \n"+
" \n"+
"DIRECTIONS: Please complete all sections. Every bit of information can be used by the Faculty Council to assist with the selection process. Completion of this form does not guarantee selection. \n"+
" \n"+
"You are advised to prepare your responses in advance before you begin filling out this online form as you can not save information and return later to finish. Also, after you hit submit and before you log off, be sure to wait for the confirmation page indicating that your submission was received."

);

  form.addTextItem().setTitle("Name").createResponse(people);

  form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
     .setTitle("Current Grade")
     .setChoiceValues(["10th", "11th"]);

  form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle("Activities").setHelpText("List any extra-curricular or co-curricular activities in which you have participated during high school. Include clubs, teams, music groups, church groups, scouting, etc. Please put a return (press enter) after each activity so that it shows as a vertical list.");

  form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle("Awards").setHelpText("These should be awards or recognition associated with the above activities or with other organizations. Please put a return (press enter) after each award so that it shows as a vertical list.");

  form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle("Service").setHelpText("List any activity that might be considered volunteer service to others (family or community) and for which you received no payment; this might include such things as doing regular housework for an elderly relative, working at a soup kitchen, helping to raise funds for charity, helping to clean a park with a church group, coaching a younger group of students in a sport or cheer leading, etc. After each activity, include in parenthesis the approximate number of hours you spent doing that activity. If it is a reoccurring event, then indicate how many times per week or month you do this service activity. Please put a return (press enter) after each service activity so that it shows as a vertical list.");

  form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle("Work Experience").setHelpText("List any work experiences (those for which you were paid) that you have had since the 9th grade. Please put a return (press enter) after each work experience so that it shows as a vertical list.");

  form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle("Leadership Positions").setHelpText("List all elected or appointed leadership positions held in school, community, or work activities. List only those positions in which you were directly responsible for directing or motivating others; for example: student council, club officer, team captain, chairperson, community leader etc. Again, please put a return (press enter) after each leadership position so that it shows as a vertical list.");

  form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle("Individual Statement").setHelpText("In one paragraph, tell us why you would like to be considered for NHS membership.");

  form.addCheckboxItem().setTitle("Agreement").setHelpText("I ATTEST THAT THE INFORMATION I AM PROVIDING THE FACULTY COUNCIL FOR NHS MEMBERSHIP CONSIDERATION IS ACCURATE TO THE BEST OF MY KNOWLEDGE.").setChoiceValues(["I agree to the above statement"]);


  for (row=2; row<=values.length; row++){
    var orignallist = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    listofteachernames.push(orignallist);
  }
 var teacherchoice = form.addCheckboxItem().setTitle("Teacher Evaluators").setHelpText("Please choose eight teachers who can provide an evaluation of your character and leadership qualities. At least five must be teachers who you had during 1st or 2nd trimester of this school year. One of the eight may be your homeroom adviser and no more than two may be teachers you had last year. You may NOT list a coach, director or extracurricular adviser unless they were also your teacher and meet the above guidelines. The evaluation form will be sent directly to, and received directly from, the teachers you choose. You don't need to do anything else after you select the teachers below.")
  .setChoiceValues(listofteachernames);

  var checkBoxValidation = FormApp.createCheckboxValidation()
  .requireSelectExactly(8)
  .build();
teacherchoice.setValidation(checkBoxValidation);

}
```

Does anyone have insight on if this even works the way I'm thinking to auto populate names in the form using the People API and if so how to make it actually work?

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: What happens if you run the example code from that page? is the people api even active for you?

Comment: Yes the api is active, I was able to return my name testing it. The api project dashboard shows 4 calls with 0% error but the data isn't populating the field in the form.

Comment: So I think I know why it isn't working, personFields: 'names' returns to much for a text item response. What I need is to just pull the display name from 'names' but I haven't found documentation on how to do that yet.

Comment: Why are you trying to pull their names into the forms? Could you collect their email addresses and then use that to look up just the person you need and add it to the spreadsheet after you submit?

Comment: This is part of a larger process that I'm trying to automate, after the student submits their form the teachers that they selected for the teacherchoice checkbox are sent a form to evaluate the student. I have a different script that sorts the data to give each teacher a list of students to evaluate, and then another script to compile the scores of the evaluation. Right now it is a manual process like you describe, the issue being it is for hundreds of students making it labor intensive.